# Converting list of dictionary to list of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have list of dictionary like below

```
dictList = [{'key': 'ABORT_DETACHED_QUERY', 'value': 'false'}, {'key': 'ALLOW_CLIENT_MFA_CACHING', 'value': 'false'}, {'key': 'ALLOW_ID_TOKEN', 'value': 'false'}]
```

I want to convert it like below

```
List1= [['ABORT_DETACHED_QUERY', 'false'], ['ALLOW_CLIENT_MFA_CACHING', 'false'], ['ALLOW_ID_TOKEN', 'false']]
```

Appreciate your help !

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Write this code for me” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension, where you iterate each dictionary in the list, and get the list of values only for each dictionary:

```py
List1 = [[*item.values()] for item in dictList]
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
[['ABORT_DETACHED_QUERY', 'false'], ['ALLOW_CLIENT_MFA_CACHING', 'false'], ['ALLOW_ID_TOKEN', 'false']]
```

Comment: Thanks much !  It is giving me syntax error   >>> dictList

[{'value': 'false', 'key': 'ABORT_DETACHED_QUERY'}, {'value': 'false', 'key': 'ALLOW_CLIENT_MFA_CACHING'}, {'value': 'false', 'key': 'ALLOW_ID_TOKEN'}]

>>> List1 = [[ *item.values()] for item in dictList]]

  File "<stdin>", line 1

    List1 = [[ *item.values()] for item in dictList]]

               ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Which Python version do you have? @Koushur

Comment: I am using python3 for this

Comment: I'm using `3.7.5` and it works fine, try this: `[list(item.values()) for item in dictList]`

Comment: Actually it worked.  My bad there.  Appreciate your help